# No-slip condition tangential and normal component decomposition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vector-fields, boundary-conditions, potential-flow

No-slip condition on a corrugated surface (modelled by a sinusoidal function $b(x)$))

$\vec{ u} (x,b(x)) =u \vec{i}+ w \vec{k} = 0 \vec{i} + 0 \vec{k}$
expressing in terms of the stream function :
$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}(x,b(x)) \vec{i}-\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}(x,b(x))  \vec{k} = 0 \vec{i} + 0 \vec{k} $$

The  tangential and normal component decomposition are given by:

\begin{equation} \label{eq:tan}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}b'(x) |_{z=b(x)}=0, \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:norm} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}b'(x)-\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}|_{z=b(x
)}=0 . \end{equation}

I don't understand this as I don't understand why the normal and tangent vectors would be:

$$\vec{n}=\vec{i}-\frac{d}{dx} b(x) \vec{k}$$
$$\vec{t}=\vec{i}\frac{d}{dx}b(x)+\vec{j} $$

(which is the onyl way I can see to get the result).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Let s be distance measured along the surface and $\phi$ be the contour angle of the surface.  Then, $$\cos{\phi}=\frac{dx}{ds}$$and $$\sin{\phi}=\frac{dz}{ds}$$The unit tangent to the surface is $$\hat{\tau}=\cos{\phi}\hat{i}+\sin{\phi}\hat{k}$$The derivative to the unit tangent with respect to distance along the surface is $$\frac{d\hat{\tau}}{ds}=-\sin{\phi}\frac{d\phi}{ds}\hat{i}+\cos{\phi}\frac{d\phi}{ds}\hat{k}=(-\sin{\phi}\hat{i}+\cos{\phi}\hat{k})\frac{d\phi}{ds}$$The derivative of the unit tangent vector is perpendicular to the unit tangent, and so it must be proportional to the normal to the surface.  In particular, the unit normal is $$\hat{n}=(-\sin{\phi}\hat{i}+\cos{\phi}\hat{k})$$For $|\frac{db}{dx}|<<1$, $dx\approx ds$, $\cos{\phi}\approx 1$, and $\sin{\phi} \approx\frac{db}{dx}$.

Comment: thank you. why is the tangent vector given by \vec{t}=dx/ds \vec{i} + dz/ds \vec{k} though?

Comment: could one equally choose the normal vector as n=sin \phi i - cos \phi k ? thanks.

Comment: The components of a tangent vector are dx in the x direction and dz in the z direction.  So the components of the unit tangent vector are $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}}$ and $\frac{dy}{\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}}$

Comment: Yes, the equation you wrote is also a unit normal.

Comment: This is still giving me a sign out: so I have the unit tangent and normal vectors are given by: $\vec{t}=\vec{i}+\frac{db}{dx}\vec{k}$,  $\vec{n}=\vec{k}-\frac{db}{dx}\vec{i}$, when used on \vec{u}=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}- \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z} , give incorrect signs compared to the stated results, thanks

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: so the stated result is incorrect?

Comment: It iii correct for small deviations of the free surface

Comment: the sign error?

Comment: You need to make sure that the signs are correct.

Comment: I am stuck on the upper plate no -slip condition as well at $z=h$, the condition is:

$\vec{u}= u \vec{i} + w \vec{k}= 1 \vec{i} + 0 \vec{k}$

expressing in terms of the stream function this is :
$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}(x,b(x)) \vec{i}-\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}(x,b(x))  \vec{k} = 1 \vec{i} + 0 \vec{k} $$ (1)

From this the condition split into tangential and normal components is given as:
$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}(x,h)  =1$
$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}(x,h) =0$ (3)

Comment: I don't really know what to do or how to get this.
If I have the tangent vector given as $ \vec{t}= dx \vec{i} + dz \vec{k}$, taking this scalar product with (1) is not going to give (3). And I also get an ugly expression if I normalise it by $\sqrt{dx^2+dz^2}$. Thanks

).